# MATLAB - Stitch Together Multiple Files

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB programming and some of the syntax escapes me. So I need a little help. Plus I need some complex looping ideas.

**Here's the breakdown of what I have**:

- 12 seperate `.dat` files, each titled something like `output_1_x.dat`, `output_2_x.dat`, etc.
- each file is actually one piece of a whole that was seperated and processed
- each `.dat` file is approx. 3.9 GB

**Here's what I need to do**:

- create a single file containing all the data from each seperate file, i.e. I need to recreate the original file.
- call this complete output file something like `output_final.dat`
- it has to be done in MATLAB, there are no other alternatives (actually there maybe; see note below)

**What is implied**:

- I will have to `fread` each 3.9 GBfile into chunks or packets, probably 100 mb at a time (using an imbedded loop?)
- these packets will have to be read then written sequentially
- after one file is read then written into `output_final.dat`, the next file is automatically read & written (the master loop).

Well, that's pretty much it. I did a search for 'merging mulitple files' and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957121/merging-multiple-files-into-one-file-by-using-matlab"). That isn't exactly what I need to do...I don't need to take part of a file, or data from files, and write it to a new one. I'm simply...concatenating...? This would be simple in Java or Perl, but I only have MATLAB as a tool.

Note: I am however running KDE in OpenSUSE on a pretty powerful box. Maybe someone who is also an expert in terminal knows a command/script to do this from the kernel?

Comment: so you just want to concatenate 12 files one after the other?

Comment: pretty much, except for I need to do it in chunks so I don't overload the memory buffer. so I'll need a for loop that runs until all files are written to output_final. Then inside that loops I'll need a loop that breaks each individual file into 100 MB chunks ~390 times. That imbedded loop writes each 100 MB chunk sequentially into the file loop memory buffer. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So on this site we usually would point you to [whathaveyoutried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) but this question is well phrased.

I wont write the code but i will give you how I would do it. So first I am a bit confused about why you need to `fread` the file. Are you just appending one file onto the end of another?

You can actually use unix commands to achieve what you want:

```
files = dir('*.dat');
for i = 1:length(files)
    string = sprintf('cat %s >> output_final.dat.temp', files(i).name);
    unix(string);
end
```

That code should loop through all the files and pipe all of the content into `output_final.dat.temp` (then just rename it, we didn't want it to be included in anything);

But if you really want to use `fread` because you want to parse the lines in some manner then you can use the same process:

```
files = dir('*.dat');
fidF = fopen('output_final.dat', 'w');
for i = 1:length(files)
    fid = fopen(files(i).name);
    while(~feof(fid))
        string = fgetl(fid) %You may choose to parse the string in some manner here
        fprintf(fidF, '%s', string)
    end
end
```

Just remember, if you are not parsing the lines this will take much much longer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That Unix code makes perfect sense. Could I break each file up into smaller chunks though? As in, read file_1 and write it into 390 100MB chunks into the output (concatenated), then when that's complete, loop onto file_2 (to concatenate onto the end of file_1)?

Comment: And yes, to clarify, we are just appending one file onto another. So...as a vector in MATLAB `output_final = [file1:file12];` -- literally just raw data hooked up in a train, car to car.

Comment: @endowdly why do you want the data to be in 100MB chunks?

Comment: @endowdly Also yes, you can `head` and `tail` it into different sized chunks, im just not sure why you would want to do it this way.

Comment: @endowdly Alternatively you can use `split` and define the file size or the number of lines.

Comment: it's simply a memory buffer guard. we're running the algorithim on a specialized box that also runs a high end signal generator and analyzer in the background, so we're trying to limit the amount of data that gets stored in virtual memory so hard processes can stay up. ...if that makes sense. Thanks for all the help. I'll working on this and post any working final code for reference.

Comment: After testing we were able to determine that this unix code does not write directly to v mem. While the `fread` and `fwrite` script does. Incorporating `split` is important to get good ram performance when using the read/write method. But, when using the Unix code, no file division is necessary. The unix code cats the files perfectly; if you use assign the files to vectors, then use `fseek` to pull out the first and last 100 columns of data in each file and compare those columns to their corresponding location in output, you get perfect matches across the board. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @endowdly No problem, glad i could help. If you feel like it you can mark as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [matlab.io.matfileclass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.matfileclass.html) objects on two of the files:

```
matObj1 = matfile('datafile1.mat')
matObj2 = matfile('datafile2.mat')
```

This does not load any data into memory. Then you can use the objects' methods to sequentialy save a variable from one file to another.

```
matObj1.varName = matObj2.varName
```

You can get all the variables in one file with `fieldnames(mathObj1)` and loop through to copy contents from one file to another. You can then clear some space by removing the copied fields. Or you can use a bit more risky procedure by directly moving the data:

```
matObj1.varName = rmfield(matObj2,'varName')
```

Just a disclaimer: haven't tried it, use at own risk.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll give it a try on some test files and see how it works. Will let you know.

Comment: This method works for smaller files that are easier to manage. We weren't able to get this to work 100% with our larger test files; they didn't run through our error check script. Interesting idea though.